# Filter 'comment_notification_text' not working

Tags: php, filters

I am wanting to edit the content that is sent to admins in the comment moderation email notification. I have looked at multiple places and they all seem to give roughly the same example to achieve this, but it isn't working for me.

I am adding this to my functions.php file:

```
add_filter('comment_notification_text', 'my_comment_notification_text', 10, 2);

function my_comment_notification_text($notify_message, $comment_id) {

  return $notify_message . ' This is some extra text that I want to add';
}
```

The additional text isn't being added to the notification. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this hook instead: `comment_moderation_text`.
[The args are the same](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_moderation_text/).

Comment: That worked! Thanks very much.